# Spring boot populates all headers, even though i specified required header name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-headers

I am sending an header `lastevaluatedkey:{"a":"b","c":23}` along with other headers in my request.

```
Controller.java

(@RequestHeader("lastevaluatedkey") Map<String,AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey){
 System.out.println(lastEvaluatedKey.heySet()); // returns all headers like accept, host etc.
}
```

Why i am getting all headers instead of just one i.e lastevaluatedkey?

Comment: Because you are injecting it into a `Map` instead of a single or collection type.

Comment: @M.Deinum but i have specified the required header name, shouldn't i get only that header? I require map as the lastevaluated header is of map<string,attributevalue> type.

Comment: No. With a Map that is ignored and you always get all the headers, that only works with a single or collection type.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can i use single or collection type to extract only the required header?

Comment: Just use a `String` as the type then parse yourself using an `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: **Read the documentation**. i.e. the javadoc of [`@RequestHeader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html): *"If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>`, `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, or `HttpHeaders` then the **map is populated with all header names and values**."*